# How Can I Segregate data in pandas From my Timestamp Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am working with an Excel sheet with pandas where I am analysing some data from it.

Inside the excel sheet I have 8 Columns one is Timestamp and another one is City column and so on like Domain, State etc.

I want to analyse city and timestamp columns only.

I have selected the city and Timestamp column from the excel sheet inside a Data Frame. I have find out the city count, means how many rows contain the same city using `cities_df['Count'] = df['City_Town_Village '].value_counts()`

After finding the city count I have find out the percentages of all the cities using `cities_df['PctCnt'] =(cities_df['Count']/sum(cities_df['Count'])*100).apply("{0:.2f}".format)`

Now my question here is, As I am finding the city_count The rows inside my dataframe is decreasing means my df has 238 rows but after the count they are decreasing to 128 no issue at all till now. They are decreasing just because of the count.

I also have the timestamp column inside my df, lets say for city *Delhi* some people registered in 28-May-2021 and some people registered in 29-May-2021 just like that. But after finding out the city_count my df is just showing me timestamp for the beginning date only i.e 28-may..

I don't know why this is happening, actually I want to segregate the data into two week and want to plot the graph on week wise. and also for city percentage.

Here is my [Excel file](https://fotuk.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/PCS_NWR_Sheet.xlsx)

This is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('PCS_NWR_Sheet.xlsx')
df.head()
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 300)
cities_df = pd.DataFrame()
cities_df['Count'] = df['City_Town_Village '].value_counts()
cities_df.index.names=['City']
cities_df.reset_index(inplace = True)
cities_df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp']
column_names = ['Timestamp', 'City', 'Count']
cities_df = cities_df.reindex(columns=column_names)
cities_df['PctCnt'] =(cities_df['Count']/sum(cities_df['Count'])*100).apply("{0:.2f}".format)
Metro_list = ['Hyderabad', 'Kolkata', 'Delhi', 'Pune', 'Bengaluru', 'Noida', 'Kanpur', 'Gurgaon']
top_metro=cities_df[cities_df['City'].isin(Metro_list)]
top_metro
```

Answer (score 0):

`.value_counts()` will return a series where the size is equal to the number of unique elements in what you are counting. So you are getting less rows because it is grouping those things.

I can think of two ways to solve the question (if I understand it right).

1. Do `.value_counts()` on both the date column and the city column.

```
df[['City_Town_Village','Date']].value_counts()
```

If you don't currently have your timestamps as dates, you'll need to make a date column that does that (you probably won't be able to group on datetimes since the times will vary. This will give a series where the row count is equal to the size of every existing combination of the two columns.

2. Make a separate dataframe with the value_count of the town column, and merge them. That is, if you want a column in your main dataframe that has the number of times that the town comes up ever in the data, that column is a different size (as we said), so you'll store it somewhere else but can bring it back in as needed.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['City_Town_Village'].value_counts())
df2.reset_index(inplace=True) # by fault, making the df from value_counts() will make your city/town the index, this makes a normal index)
df2.columns = ['City_Town_Village','Count'] #rename the columns
df = df.merge(df2,how='left',on='City_Town_Village')
```

This will make `df` to have the `Counts` column added, where it will be the count of the City/Town in the original dataset.